# wp_http remote request not respecting timeout

Tags: http-api, wp-remote-get, wp-remote-post, wp-remote-request

I am trying to test for timeout scenarios for my API requests using `WP_Http::request()` by passing a very short `timeout` argument (a minimal fraction of a second).  After my API requests continued to succeed regardless of my extremely low setting, I noticed that my timeout was being set to a thousand milliseconds (one second) even though I had set it much lower for testing.

Is there a way I can get around this and pass a timeout less than a second?

Simplest example:

```php
$http = new WP_Http;
$response = $http->request(
    'YOUR_URL',
    array(
        'timeout' => 0.00001,
    ),
);
```

(`timeout` is set small to test for a real-world timeout scenario, but it doesn't fail as expected unless over 1,000 ms)

Comment: can you edit your question to include the code you used? As well as how you confirmed the thousand milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is the cause in the Requests library that powers WP_HTTP:

> - Transfer & connect timeouts, in seconds & milliseconds
>
> cURL is unable to handle timeouts under a second in DNS lookups, so we round
> those up to ensure 1-999ms isn't counted as an instant failure.

The code looks to be here:

https://github.com/WordPress/Requests/blob/90db63ab54449c071fc2192a4fc3487cafbf67d0/src/Transport/Curl.php#L448-L460

```php
        if (is_int($timeout) || $this->version < self::CURL_7_16_2) {
            curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, ceil($timeout));
        } else {
            // phpcs:ignore PHPCompatibility.Constants.NewConstants.curlopt_timeout_msFound
            curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, round($timeout * 1000));
        }
```

If your goal is to test that a response time is within a certain limit by using the timeout so it fails when it takes too long, as clever as it sounds there are other things that interfere. Instead timing the request at the API server side, and at the client side, then using the time taken to implement your own timeout test would be more reliable ( and give you the opportunity to add more logic, e.g. a warning threshold ).

https://github.com/WordPress/Requests/issues/58

It's also possible your server is using an old version of curl that does not support microsecond based timeouts

Comment: According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/321321/upgrade-curl-to-latest-on-centos#:~:text=We%20specifically%20need%20a%20feature%20introduced%20in%207.16.2%2C%20CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS%20for%20setting%20really%20small%20timeouts.) and as noted in the code you provided (via `$this->version < self::CURL_7_16_2` comparison), `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` was introduced in 7.16.2 and I'm running 7.68.0 so that's not the case.

Comment: One hacky solution that's working for me is to *temporarily* replace the lines referred to above in `wp-includes/Requests/src/Transport/Curl.php` with `curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);`

Comment: true but I've got to write an answer for all the people who have the question as written, not just you, otherwise someone else will read it and get confused then pop up in a years time with a comment, need to cover all bases! You could also use another library such as Guzzle to make the requests if you really want to repurpose timeout this way though

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstand me; your answer was extremely helpful and it was highly appreciated.  I wasn't trying to correct your answer with an alternative solution; I was simply just throwing another idea out there in case it might also help someone.  Maybe I should have added it as an additional answer instead of as a comment.